# Can I use AutoMapper with Blazor?

Tags: automapper, blazor

Can I use AutoMapper 8.0.1 with Blazor server app, please?
I have try it but my code always run into an error:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types:
> Object -> Object System.Object -> System.Object

I have added the mapper to the Startup file:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

I have created the profile:

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<District, DistrictModel>();
    }
}
```

And I try to use it:

```
[Inject]
protected IMapper Mapper { get; set; }
District district = DistrictService.FindDistrictById(districtId);
DistrictModel model = Mapper.Map<DistrictModel>(district);
```

The AssertConfigurationIsValid method gives:

```
Cannot find any profiles with the name 'MyProfile'. (Parameter 'profileName')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in your services in startup :

it's reusable and cleaner

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

add these to interface and class in your project

```
public interface IMapFrom<T>
{
        void Mapping(Profile profile) => profile.CreateMap(typeof(T), GetType());
}
```

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            ApplyMappingsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }

        private void ApplyMappingsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
        {
                var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces()
                .Any(i =>i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapFrom<>)))
                .ToList();

            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Mapping")
                    ?? type.GetInterface("IMapFrom`1").GetMethod("Mapping");

                methodInfo?.Invoke(instance, new object[] { this });

            }
        }
    }
```

your model or viewmodel :

```
 public class District : IMapFrom<District>
    {
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public void Mapping(Profile profile)
        {
            profile.CreateMap<District, DistrictModel>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: He is asking for use in a Blazor component. What you have suggested is for MVC.

Answer (score 5):

`Startup.cs`

```
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(configuration =>
{
    configuration.AddProfile(new MyProfile());
});

var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();

services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```